# How to properly create unit tests for recursive methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, recursion, reactive-programming

I have one recursive procedure that has to be run multiple times depending on the output. The method `refreshInBatches()` runs a query in the database and returns a `nodeId`. The stop condition is: whenever I reach the end node (let's say it has id = 1) or I reach a node that has been visited before.
To check the latter, I created a Set and to keep calling the method to refresh in batches I added a do-while loop. `notEndNode()` returns `true` if it hasn't reached the stop condition and `false` otherwise.

```
public Mono<MyClass> refresh(String databaseName, Long nodeId, Integer batchSize, Set<Long> visitedNodes) {
    Mono<MyClass> result = null;
    do {
      addNodeToSet(visitedNodes, result);
      result = refreshInBatches(databaseName, nodeId, batchSize);
    } while (notEndNode(nodeId, result.block(), visitedNodes));
    return result;
  }
```

I am trying to find a good approach to add unit tests to this behavior that I just explained. I wanted to mock the DB response because I only want to test how many times I'm calling the db (through the `refresh()` method). So I have created a mock response list with 5 elements with the last one being the end node (meaning that the procedure should stop after that).

The mock starts from `refreshInBatches()` that always should return the `response` object. The mocked object `node` should be returned from `response`, and I added a iterator to the list so we could get the next value whenever we tried to get the `nodeId`.
The above test can be found below. But it's not working the way I expected. When I try to debug the application, the first time `refreshInBatches()` is called, I get `10L` as expected. But if I keep iterating over the loop, `refreshInBatches()` is going to be called for the second time, but `10L` is returned again, not `iterator.next()`. Resulting on `dbRepository.refreshInBatches()` getting called only 2 times instead of 5.

```
  @InjectMocks
  DbRepository dbRepository = Mockito.spy(new DbRepository(dbClient, null));

  MyClass response = Mockito.spy(new MyClass());

  @Mock
  Node node = Mockito.mock(Node.class);

  @Test
  public void testRefreshDBShouldCallTheRefreshMethodFiveTimes() {

    List<Value> setIds = Arrays.asList(Values.value(10L), Values.value(20L), Values.value(50L), Values.value(60L), Values.value(1L));
    Iterator<Value> iterator = setIds.iterator();
    Mockito.doReturn(iterator.next()).when(node).get(anyString());
    Mockito.doReturn(node).when(response).getNode();
    Mockito.doReturn(Mono.just(response)).when(dbRepository).refreshInBatches(anyString(), anyLong(), anyInt());
    dbRepository.refresh("dataBase", -1L, 10000, new HashSet<>());
    verify(dbRepository, times(setIds.size())).refreshInBatches(anyString(), anyLong(), anyInt());
  }
```

I think my code has some design flaws, but I would like to understand how could one test recursive calls with mock responses. Shouldn't the iterator have moved to the next element the second time `dbRepository.refreshInBatches()` was called? Or at least when one of those checks were called:

```
  private void addNodeToSet(Set<Long> visited, Mono<MyClass> projection) {
    if (ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(projection) && ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(projection.block())) {
      visited.add(projection.block().getNode().get("id").asLong());
    }
  }

  private static boolean notEndNode(Long nodeId, MyClass projection, Set<Long> visited) {
    return projection != null &&
        ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(projection.getNode()) &&
        !nodeId.equals(projection.getNode().get("id").asLong()) &&
        !visited.contains(projection.getNode().get("id").asLong());
  }
```

Comment: 1. Look at the Java doc and make sure you test all conditions and output mentioned there.  2.  White box test and make sure you test all branches in the method.  That's how I do it.

Comment: The parameter you pass to `doReturn` is evaluated once, when you call `doReturn` -- you are not passing a lambda, it can be no other way. If you want to return different values chain `thenReturn` or use `doAnswer`.